# element-wise addition from two list: why not this work?

Tags: python

Why this code not working for element-wise addition? I know I can use map function.

```
list1=[3,4,5]
list2=[4,5,6]
result=[]
def addition(x,y):
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            return result.append(i+j)

print(addition(list1,list2))
```

Comment: what is the desired output of this? may be you want `[i+j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]` if I guessed it correct

Answer (score 2):

You should not call return on the .append operation, you are just returning from the function on the 1st iteration.

If you want element wise addition you should iterate the two lists together.

```
list1=[3,4,5]
list2=[4,5,6]
result=[]
def addition(x,y):
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        result.append(i+j)
    return result
print(addition(list1,list2))
```